# How to parse an xml and extract the xslt element from it in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, browser

I am sending an xml response from my servlet to my html page. I receive it via the xmlresponse object of the xmlhttprequest object. My xml document contains a xsl:stylesheet as an element I want to extract this element and execute that xslt code in my java script.
Is it possible?
This is my xml code :

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2012-05-22T13:40:52:390" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:na
mes:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="localhos
t:8080/consumer.jsp">
<UserID>
   xyz
</UserID>
<testing>
   text
</testing>
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   http://localhost:8080/saml/SProvider.jsp
</saml:Issuer>
<xslt>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/">
UserID : <xsl:copy-of select="//UserID"/>
testing : <xsl:copy-of select="//testing"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</xslt>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Once I get this xml string from the ajax response, I want to convert it into xml, extract the xslt part and execute it and show the output in a text area.
**EDIT2**
What is wrong with this code :

```
    var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
     //var xmltext=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
     var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
var element=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform","stylesheet");//
 //document.forms['my']['signature'].value=xmltext;
var stylesheet=xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(element[0]);
var result=xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
 var xmltext1=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(result);
document.forms['my']['signature2'].value = xmltext1;
```

The output(xmltext1) for the xslt transformation is -

```
<transformiix:result xmlns:transformiix="http://www.mozilla.org/TransforMiix">
UserID : 1212

Testing : 1212
</transformiix:result>
```

But if you see in the xslt code, the outputmethod is set to "text". then why are xml tags included in the output?

**Answer**
[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) gives the exlpanation for **edit2**. Thanks for the answers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, though I only tested it in the newest chrome:

```
var getNsResolver = function (element) {
  var ns = {
    samlp: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol',
    xsl: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
  };

  return function (prefix) {
    return ns[prefix] || null;
  };
};

var handleResponse = function (xhr) {
  var
    doc = xhr.responseXML,
    xsl = doc.evaluate('/samlp:AuthnRequest/xslt/xsl:stylesheet', doc, getNsResolver(doc.documentElement), XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext(),
    processor = new XSLTProcessor(),
    result;

  processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  result = processor.transformToFragment(doc, document);

  document.getElementById('foo').value = result.textContent;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    handleResponse(request);
  }, false);

  request.open('GET', 'sample.xml', true); // sample.xml contains the xml from the question
  request.send();
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried a piece of code. I cannot figure out where I went wrong. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Ashwin have you tried to use the code I posted? What you added differs greatly.

Comment: @Ashwin I changed the code a bit (the `handleResponse` function). Also  as I read your comment on Christophes answer, I'd like to suggest: don't use w3schools as a reference, see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) for reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to get namespaced xml from an xmlHttpRequest (in your case ns=xsl, not tested):

```
var xml=xhr.responseXML;
var elts = (xml.getElementsByTagNameNS)?xml.getElementsByTagNameNS("ns","tag"):xml.getElementsByTagName("ns\:tag");
```

Note that you can only use responseXML if the server returns well formed xml. If not, you'll need to parse xhr.responseText.

Comment: I read your edit, there no such method as getElementsByTag. Which browser did you use for the test?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to use getElementsByTagNameNS(). I have edited the code. Still the same problem. For getElementsByTagNameNS() see http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getelementsbytagnamens.asp I am using mozilla

Comment: That's what I have in my code ;-) Maybe the issue is that your response doesn't start with a regular xml header? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Comment: To clarify, getElementsByTagNameNS is not supported by all browsers, this is why my code includes a fallback to getElementsByTagName

Comment: it works fine now. I have posted the reason at the end of my question. thank you:)

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again. But the code that I mentioned in my question edit2 works only in mozilla. It does not work in google chrome(the part where xslt is processed is not working)I also tried it with getelmentsbytagname("ns\:tag"). It only does not work in chrome. It even works in IE!

Comment: Not sure why. Do you have a recent version of Chrome? I recall testing my code in IE, Firefox and Chrome (not with xsl though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this ATM, works great!
Its a parser written on jQuery

http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/